# Are Couchbase questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, questions, asking-questions

I noticed that there was no tag for Couchbase and only a small number of questions mentioning it.

So are Couchbase questions on-topic for this site - dba.SE (it which case it'd be lovely to get a *tag*), or do the belong on SO, Security.SE, SF, or something similar?

Comment: Absolutely they are.  There is a tag [tag:CouchDB] for these questions.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells #couchdb is for [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). _[Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/)_ is a wholly distinct database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couchbase is a [Document-Oriented NoSQL Database](http://www.couchbase.com/) according to the title of their home page: that puts it on-topic, though of course the NoSQL market is more fragmented and more cutting-edge, meaning each DB has it's own niche and the pool of Q&A here may never be big.

It does seem to be [related from a technology perspective](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-vs-couchdb) to CouchDB, though not so closely that they should share a tag. So, how do we get a [couchbase](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/couchbase) tag? All we need is two open questions with the tag. If there is just one, and no follow-up within a few months, the tag will auto-delete ([unless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127700/166851) someone takes the trouble to write the tag Wiki).

So, please ask (and answer?) some good Couchbase questions on the site :)

Comment: So to create a tag, could I just write a (useful) question and later onwards another, and each time, simply tag them as `couchbase`? Or would I need a higher rep level?

Comment: You personally would need a higher level rep, but you could always flag for a mod. Once it's created, you can use it freely.

Comment: @haneefmubarak what jcolebrand said ^^^^^^

Comment: So @haneefmubarak, let's be having those useful [tag:couchbase] questions then? :)

Comment: Yep. Just as soon as I start running into them (which gives an estimate of less than a day) XD